# how create left join query with sails.js

Tags: sails.js, left-join

I would like do a **left** join query in sails.js. I think i should use populate

I have three models

```
caracteristique{
    id,
    name,
    races:{
      collection: 'race',
      via: 'idcaracteristique',
      through: 'racecaracteristique'
    },
}

race{
    id,
    name,
    caracteristiques:{
          collection: 'caracteristique',
          via: 'idrace',
          through: 'racecaracteristique'
        }
    }

RaceCarecteristique{
idrace: {
      model:'race'
    },
idcaracteristique: {
      model: 'caracteristique'
    },
bonusracial:{
      type: 'number',
}
```

My data are:

```
Table Caracteristiques
id  name
1 | strength
2 | dex
3 | Charisme

Table Race
id   name 
1 | human
2 | Org

TableRaceCarecteristique
idrace idcaracteristique bonusracial
1      | 2               | +2
```

This sql request give me for human,  all caracteristiques and if exist bonusracial

```
'SELECT caracteristique.id, caracteristique.name, bonusracial
FROM caracteristique 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select idcaracteristique, bonusracial 
                  from racecaracteristique 
                  where idrace=$1 ) as q 
ON  q.idcaracteristique = caracteristique.id';
```

I have this result:

```
caracteristique.id, caracteristique.name, bonusracial
1 | strength | null
2 | dex | 2
3 | Charisme | null
```

How use populate to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a SQL-database adapter (MySQL, PQSL etc) you can utilise a method for performing actual, handwritten SQL statements. When all else fails, this might be your best bet to find an acceptable solution, within the framework.

The `.sendNativeQuery()` method sends your parameterized SQL statement to the native driver, and responds with a raw, non-ORM-mangled result. Actual database-schema specific tables and columns appear in the result, so you need to be careful with changes to models etc. as they might change the schema in the backend database.

The method takes two parameters, the parameterized query, and the array of values to be inserted. The array is optional and can be omitted if you have no parameters to replace in the SQL statement.

Using your already parameterized query from above, I'm sending the query to fetch the data for an "org" (orc perhaps?) in the example below. See the docs linked at the bottom.

**Code time:**

```js
let query = `
SELECT caracteristique.id, caracteristique.name, bonusracial
FROM caracteristique 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select idcaracteristique, bonusracial 
                  from racecaracteristique 
                  where idrace=$1 ) as q 
ON  q.idcaracteristique = caracteristique.id`;

var rawResult = await sails.sendNativeQuery(query, [ 2 ]);
console.log(rawResult);
```

**Docs:** [`.sendNativeQuery()`](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/datastores/send-native-query)

Comment: Thanks ! i will use sendnativequery

Comment: @AntoineMoulin Great! Glad I could help. Please remember to mark accepted answers as such. It helps others find the answers to their questions about the same topic.

Comment: @AntoineMoulin Thank you!